# How to get the revision of a specific file using SVNKit?

Tags: file, revision, svnkit

Given a file, how do i get its revision in the repository without checking it out? Is there a way or function in SVNKit that allow me to do so?

For example I hava a file named foo.java, how would i know the current revision of the file without checking it out?

It'll would be nice if you can provide same code snippet.

Thank You very much

Linda

Answer (score 0):

The `SVNRepository` class has two `getFileRevisions` methods.

I haven't used either method, but it appears from the documentation that you get a revision history from a start revision number to an ending revision number.  Specifying 0 and last revision number, respectively, gives the complete revision history.